# Significant Figures in quantity?

Tags: chemistry

I am still having trouble grasping significant figures.

How many significant figures would be in this quantity?

$01010.0$

I feel like it is 3, but not quite sure.

Comment: @hardmath there you go

Comment: Should be 5.  The only reason you would include the 0 to the right of the decimal would be because it was significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though it is correct as written, with 5 digits. There is only .0 behind 1010.

Answer (score 1):

It should be 5. If I recall correctly, when you explicitly add zeroes on the end of a decimal then they count as significant figures.

EDIT: [source](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/phys/Dept2/APPhys1/sigfigs/sigfig/node12.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's $5$ significant digits, the zero in front does not mean anything. The $1010$ is all significant because the zero i sandwiched between and there is a decimal point, and the $.0$ is also significant because it tells you we measured to this decimal point.